# changing JRE in Wildly deployemnt WAR file

Tags: java, deployment, wildfly

I have project where there are 8 WAR files deployed using JRE 11.
but i need a particular WAR file to be running using JRE 8.

is it possible to make a partiular WAR file to be running using a separate JRE. when the other WAR's and wildfly service is running in a different JRE.

is it possible to make a partiular WAR file to be running using a separate JRE. when the other WAR's and wildfly service is running in a different JRE.

Comment: No, that's not possible.  At the lowest level there is a single operating system process that runs Wildfly and, within Wildfly are the WAR files.  That O/S process is a Java 11 or Java 8 JRE.  Your best bet would be to either upgrade the Java 8 code (it's strange that it can't run in a newer JRE) or have a separate Wildfly process for the Java 8 and Java 11 code.